# Get and store value from Firebird db (C#)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a Firebird database which contains several tables. 
So I need to select last row from one table, find id value from the row and then use this id value in my next select by another FB table. It works fine but I want to know is there a way to simplify my method?

```
string connectionString = "bla-bla-bla ...";

FbConnection selectConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);
selectConnection.Open();

FbCommand readCommand = new FbCommand("select ID_WEIGH, BRUTTO from cars_result rows (select count(*) from cars_result) to (select count(*) from cars_result)", selectConnection);
FbDataReader reader_1 = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader_1.Read())
{
    string current_id = reader_1[0];
    string select_string = "select ID_WEIGH, NUM, WEIGHT from axis_detail where ID_WEIGH="+str(current_id);
}
    reader_1.Close();
```

And after that actions I need to construct new FbDataReader and make select from another table using select_string. So is there a way just to store last row from one table into variable and then use it value? For example like python-web2py way where I can store exact row from DB into one variable and then I can get every value using column names:

```
search_row = db(db.trucks.num == request.vars.num).select().first()
```

or

```
search_row = db.trucks[request.vars.truck]
```

And now I can do:

```
truck = search_row.num
```

Is there a similar trick in C# & Firebird?

Comment: You may think your query selects the last record, but it doesn't as you didn't specify an `order by`, and so the order depends on the plan and storage order of rows. However the obvious solution is to only use one query, and not two (which also contains a potential SQL injection).

Comment: BTW: If you want similar tricks in C# as in python, you need to look at Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: you can create a selectable stored procedure.there you can store query fields/results into variables.then call it once in your c# code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
using System.data;
        
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (FbDataReader read = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(read);
}
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
```

And call column value:

```
string columnvalue = row["COLUMNNAME"].toString();
```